# Unable to access Apache Web Server from a remote computer

Tags: apache, networking, router

My problem is almost the same, as this one - [How to access apache behind home router](https://superuser.com/questions/119840/how-to-access-apache-behind-home-router). However, this link did not help me at all. So, I have public IP 176.XXX.YYY.ZZ. I have an Apache Web Server and I can access a test-page locally by:

```
http://localhost
```

My TP-LINK router IP adress is 192.168.0.1. I can access its settings page by:

```
http://192.168.0.1
```

In redirection page of the router settings I added a virtual web-server: port 80, IP 192.168.0.1.

When I try to access a web-page from a remote computer (`http://public_ip` or `http://192.168.0.1`), I'm redirected to the router settings page.

`httpd.conf` now contains

```
Listen: *:80
```

Comment: in router settings add a virtual web-server with the internal ip of your apache server machine, not the address of the router

Comment: Does it differ from public IP of the web server? If, so, then when I set it in my router settings, I got an error, that there is no such an IP in my local network

Comment: You need to tell the router where to forward requests coming from outside. The router IP is 192.168.0.1, your apache machine has an address of 192.168.0.x where x is not 1. You need to set this IP to your router

Comment: Thank you, sir! I set it to 192.168.0.100 and now it works! If you place your comment in the answer block, I will mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the router where to forward requests coming from outside. The router IP is 192.168.0.1, your apache machine has an address of 192.168.0.x where x is not 1. You need to set this IP to your router